# loop through json arrays with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "title": "Star Chart",
    "locations": [
        {
            "name": "Mercury",
            "faction": "Grineer",
            "enemyLvl": "6 - 11",
            "missCount": "11 Missions",
            "missions": [
                {
                    "name": "Apollodorus",
                    "target": "Infestation",
                    "type": "Survival",
                    "planet": "Mercury"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Boethius",
                    "target": "Infestation",
                    "type": "Exterminate",
                    "planet": "Mercury"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Venus",
            "faction": "Corpus",
            "enemyLvl": "3 - 18",
            "missCount": "14 Missions",
            "missions": [
                {
                    "name": "Aphrodite",
                    "target": "Corpus",
                    "type": "Mobile Defense",
                    "planet": "Venus"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Cytherean",
                    "target": "Corpus",
                    "type": "Interception",
                    "planet": "Venus"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My problem is that at Location 2 I get the same Mission results from Location 1.

Please see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s3739/aovb7wre/) to know what I mean.
And maybe I'll get some help with setting the mission count correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here: `$(data.locations[0].missions).each...` It's hardcored to `0`. Use `index` instead.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/aovb7wre/1/